# php mysql script not working

Tags: php, mysql

I got my script working for one column of data but I am trying to send it other data to a second column in mysql table. Here's my php code:

```
<?php
function db_connect()
{
$hostname = '127.0.0.1';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = 'hit';
mysql_connect ($hostname, $db_user, $db_password) or die (mysql_error()); 
echo "Success.. Connected to MySQL...<br />"; 
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error()); 
echo "Success.. Connected to Database...<br /> "; 
}
function insertData($DATA)
{
function insterData($DATA2)
{
db_connect();
$requete = "INSERT INTO data SET col_Data='".$DATA."'";
if(!mysql_query($requete))
echo mysql_error();
else
echo 'data accepted.';
$requete2 = "INSERT INTO data SET col_Data2='".$DATA2."'";
if(!mysql_query($requete2))
echo mysql_error();
else
echo 'data accepted.';
}
if(isset($_GET['DATA']))
if(isset($_GET['DATA2']))
}
insertData($_GET['DATA']);
insertData($_GET['DATA2']);
}
else
{
echo 'Nop';
} 
?>
```

This is how I send the post data

```
http://localhost/hit.php?DATA=iamwicked&DATA2=iamcool
```

This then suppose to send `DATA=iamwicked` goes into database hit table data column col_data

This then suppose to send `DATA2=iamcool` goes into database hit table data column col_data2

But I get this error, 
but there are errors can someone help me debug.

Here is a working script:

```
<?php
function db_connect()
{
$hostname = '127.0.0.1';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = 'hit';
mysql_connect ($hostname, $db_user, $db_password) or die (mysql_error()); 
echo "Success.. Connected to MySQL...<br />"; 
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error()); 
echo "Success.. Connected to Database...<br /> "; 
}
function insertData($DATA)
{
db_connect();
$requete = "INSERT INTO data SET col_Data='".$DATA."'";
if(!mysql_query($requete))
echo mysql_error();
else
echo 'data accepted.';
}
if(isset($_GET['DATA']))
{
insertData($_GET['DATA']);
}
else
{
echo 'Nop';
}
?>
```

this is a working script when I use this url to post data

```
localhost/hit.php?DATA=iamwicked
```

When I use this it save `iamwicked` in database hit table data column col_data
so how do I fix my script to send more data to col_data2 and so forth

Comment: "i get this error" - what error? Post your error message!

Comment: $conn = mysql_connect ($hostname, $db_user, $db_password) connection resource store to a variable

Comment: i get multipul errors at the moemnt it is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in G:\TETRA\htdocs\hit.php on line 33

Comment: Please note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` functions instead. What error message are you getting?

Comment: What is this, function within function? Maybe you need closure? But it's not neccessary in your example.

Comment: `if(isset($_GET['DATA2']))}` probably is this piece of code that is returning you this error. You cannot instance an `if` statement and close it before you open it.

Comment: There are numerous errors here. Read the error message and fix the problem it is telling you about. Try again. Repeat until you're not getting basic syntax errors, then come back and ask again.

Comment: Whats this? `function insertData($DATA){function insterData($DATA2){`, is that intentional?

Comment: This code is full of mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return `$conn` connection resource #id from function

```
<?php

function db_connect()
{
    $hostname = '127.0.0.1';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_password = '';
    $db_name = 'hit';

    $conn = mysql_connect ($hostname, $db_user, $db_password) or 
            die (mysql_error()); 
    echo "Success.. Connected to MySQL...<br />"; 
    mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error()); 
    echo "Success.. Connected to Database...<br /> "; 

    return $conn;
}

$conn = db_connect();
```

To insert single field

```
function insertData($DATA)
{
    $requete = "INSERT INTO data SET col_Data='".$DATA."'";
    mysql_query($requete) or die(mysql_error());
}

if(isset($_GET['DATA'])) {
    insertData($_GET['DATA']);
}

if(isset($_GET['DATA2'])) {
    insertData($_GET['DATA2']);
}
```

**UPDATE**

To insert multiple fields

```
function insertData($DATA, $DATA2)
{
    $requete = "INSERT INTO data SET col_Data='".$DATA."', col_Data2='".$DATA2."'";
    mysql_query($requete) or die(mysql_error());
}

if(isset($_GET['DATA']) && isset($_GET['DATA2'])) {
    insertData($_GET['DATA'], $_GET['DATA2']);
}

?>
```

Comment: And what about those X number of other mistakes in their code?

Comment: okay this sort of works it works but instead of placing data in col_data and placing data2 into col_data2 it just inserts it all in col_data collum

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an wrong spelling here:

```
function insertData($DATA2) instead of function insterData($DATA2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed two problems here.

```
function insertData($DATA)
{
function insterData($DATA2)
{
```

What are you trying to achieve here? Declaring a function inside another function is totally useless (and generates errors since it's not allowed). If you want to call a function inside another one you must declare them separately and then call them, f.e.

```
function insertData($DATA)
{
    insterData($somevariable);
    //Rest of the operations
}
```

This should be clear enough. There is another error though.

```
if(isset($_GET['DATA']))
    if(isset($_GET['DATA2']))
    }
        insertData($_GET['DATA']);
        insertData($_GET['DATA2']);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Nop';
    }
```

I suppose there is a typo here, and you meant

```
if(isset($_GET['DATA2']))
{
```

Comment: could u edit my script with these corrections so i can try out i also posted a working script that only send the one DATA variable

Comment: You will never learn anything if I write your code entirely. Just try to write it yourself with the suggestions I gave you. And if you have any problem with syntax or something else, you could also visit http://php.net/